# How do I type a callback based on a parsed path in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Ultimately, my question is how do I type or implement my `watchData` function such that I can know the correct type of the `data`?

Suppose I have a `database` of `Widget`s and `Sprocket`s:

```js
type Widget = { foo: unknown, bar: unknown }
type Sprocket = { baz: unknown, qux: unknown }
type Widgets = Record<string, Widget>
type Sprockets = Record<string, Sprocket>

const database: {widgets: Widgets, sprockets: Sprockets} = {
    widgets: {
        123: { foo: 'something', bar: 'something' },
        234: { foo: 'something', bar: 'something' }
    },
    sprockets: {
        345: { baz: 'something', qux: 'something' },
        456: { baz: 'something', qux: 'something' }
    }
}
```

I want to subscribe to a function `watchData` that calls me back with the data based on a path that I supply, like this:

```js
watchData('widgets/123', data => { // compiler correctly infers `data` here
    console.log(data)
})
```

My expectation is that `data` should be typed based on parsing the `path`:

```js
type Data<Path> = Path extends `${infer Table}/${infer _Key}`
    ? (Table extends 'widgets'
        ? Widget
        : (Table extends 'sprockets' ? Sprocket : undefined))
    : Path extends `${infer Table}`
    ? (Table extends 'widgets'
        ? Widgets
        : Table extends 'sprockets' ? Sprockets : undefined)
    : undefined

type TestSomeWidget = Data<'widgets/123'>     // Correctly `Widget`
type TestSomeSprocket = Data<'sprockets/456'> // Correctly `Sprocket`
type TestAllWidgets = Data<'widgets'>         // Correctly `Widgets`
type TestAllSprockets = Data<'sprockets'>     // Correctly `Sprockets`
```

I can implement the `watchData` function simply like this, but I get TypeScript errors because I'm not calling the callback with the correct type:

```js
const watchData = <Path extends string>(path: Path, cb: (val: Data<Path>) => void): unknown => {
    const [table, key] = path.split('/')

    if (table === 'widgets' || table === 'sprockets') {
        const tableData = database[table]

        if (key) return cb(tableData[key])

        return cb(tableData)
    }

    return cb(undefined)
}
```

I don't know how to correctly implement or type this function to satisfy the TS compiler. I'd rather not have to add type assertions at the call site if I don't have to.

See the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glgEwOYWFAvFA3lAZge3wC4oBXAOwGtz8B3cgGigCMBDAJxIurvKgF8AUKEhQAymHb4AxpVQZsLVgC8uVGvSYBHUgA81PegOHho8ZKgDOCgEoRp+dggA8l4OzjkkTcymAA+E1EJKVkrW3tHFzcPLyYQmTkAwSDoABFWYFZnAAVMgAt-BTzgfKgIXWAIcgRrAAMAEixPXAh2KAAVVmYAGwh+AHomlraoAH0AaQgQfjrBKAWoAH4oAAou3ugKqprrAHJaRD9LPfnF85XfVDPzhZJ17r7yyuraqD3LSUSrPeXxL7CaDUCAguE8EAQAEpITcoCQSmVtq96sNyK12hs+rNYSsHptnjs3gcjj9YRdYCTgJYyYsSJiti9du9PqEkic-glAdZgaDwVDYTyweQISkRNAOhA3GJ8ABbCBXNCYDJZZzEixUgYARgATABmPaBMWdSXAaVyzlJBTK7IfAFsgYAFgArAA2A2pY1uACCPR6CusSsyNsO6pOhtMnuAPp6FvCgZVttZP0Cggc5DcUAQQbYlggJCwIeOJH9TBZ3ypJFjVP4CiwsMLVnzNIWOt1+bwhBIH1lqHyniQeyYbE4zJ7pX7v34DGbUD1DvbBGIo7l468g6UI+7K77a+M5ynsLLXKbt0Wuud7bYqmXvYn2j0XcsY53A4E09PC2dLsvKkfz7vUA6PoN6rq+Qj7oIQipvg6ZoLQmTSPk1oKLkBQEsiUAxP2-irGABTwgUTDSMw9wAG6sD0JDWqhpT+JCGBFKR+CIJCBgaHw6BFHW5xphmADaWSbEwcggAAugoeGlAAdJ8PRwMAqx7AMewwrCcC4GsglPOgOnvA2VK-AAPoZUBadAOmYIm5YnPR3EfrxaBmchmBZoJrC5gJjwQKJKQflA6lrCJ9HsKgpDsHwxGrE5QZ8SJomqX5IXAGFEXMFFXnWjCEGwklKVQJFFAgkKEIwlB8HAIh1qKfplhanq66uawDGKAMAz5bKYBwH07QOOwIXSMAPQgP5aJtPUjV1FA+RtBAsK8fgfRST0+BIKsjWlZCQA).

Comment: Call site or implementation? Currently the call site is fine. The implementation is the part that has all the errors.

Comment: @vera. Correct – the call site is looking fine. I'm not sure if I'd need to adjust the implementation of the function, or adjust something with the types to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do this.

Inside watchdata function, type of val is

```
Widget | Sprocket | Widgets | Sprockets | undefined
```

Which would never be affectable to a type Data, even if the types are matching. In the function time, at compile time i think they are not.

When calling the function,

```
watchData('widgets/123', data => {
```

The type of `Data<'widgets/123'>` is actually `Widget`, so compiler says OK. I think you cannot solve this.

But you can work around with a *not satisfying* cast each time you call the callback function :

```
    if (table === 'widgets' || table === 'sprockets') {
        const tableData = database[table]

        if (key) return cb(tableData[key] as Data<Path>)

        return cb(tableData as Data<Path>)
    }

    return cb(undefined  as  Data<Path>)
```

The cast will be valid (assuming your snippet is not more complicated than it looks).

---

By the way i have notice that you do not handle this case :

```
type TestSomeSprocketEmpty = Data<'sprockets/'>
```

so i suggest to adjust to :

```
type Data<Path> = Path extends `${infer Table}/${infer _Key}`? 
    _Key extends "" ? undefined : // this line
     (Table extends 'widgets'
        ? Widget
        : (Table extends 'sprockets' ? Sprocket : undefined))
    : Path extends `${infer Table}`
    ? (Table extends 'widgets'
        ? Widgets
        : Table extends 'sprockets' ? Sprockets : undefined)
    : undefined
```

---

then i have another suggest with typing Path :

```
type DBType = typeof database
type TableList = keyof DBType
type PATH = `${TableList}/${string}` | `${TableList}` | ''

type Data<Path extends PATH> = ...
```

And this type which might help also :

```
type DataHelperType = PATH extends infer X ?  X extends PATH ? Data<X> : never : never
```

wich is a dynamic equivalent to

```
type DataHelperType = Widget | Sprocket | Widgets | Sprockets | undefined
```

Comment: Love the effort here – thanks for the suggestions. I was hoping there would be a way to get it done without the type assertion, so I'll be looking out for other answers, but this definitely deserves an upvote.